# Logistic regression with opposing states with same identical variables

Tags: r, regression, logistic

I have a dataset with identical variables have opposing target variable (so instead of 0 is 1).

```
    > data.frame(y=c(y1[1],y2[1]),v1=c(v1[1],v1[1]),v2=c(v2[1],v2[1]))
  y         v1       v2
1 1 -0.6264538 1.134965
2 0 -0.6264538 1.134965
```

Does this have effect on logistic regression estimates? I run this example in `r` and it shows already impact with adding only `10` (representing ony 1% of the total dataset) such opposing variables. (Duplicating in the below example the same variables with changing (inverting) the target).

```
set.seed(1)
v1 = rnorm(1000)           # some continuous variables 
v2 = rnorm(1000)
z = 1 + 2*v1 + 3*v2        # linear combination with a bias
pr = 1/(1+exp(-z))         # pass through an inv-logit function
y1 = rbinom(1000,1,pr)      # bernoulli response variable
y2 = abs(y1-1)      # bernoulli response variable
     
#fit
df1 = data.frame(y=c(y1,y2[1:10]),v1=c(v1,v1[1:10]),v2=c(v2,v2[1:10]))
summary(glm( y~v1+v2,data=df1,family="binomial"))


# same without opposing inputs

set.seed(1)
x1 = rnorm(1000)           # some continuous variables 
x2 = rnorm(1000)
z = 1 + 2*x1 + 3*x2        # linear combination with a bias
pr = 1/(1+exp(-z))         # pass through an inv-logit function
y = rbinom(1000,1,pr)      # bernoulli response variable

#fit
df2 = data.frame(y=y,x1=x1,x2=x2)
summary(glm( y~x1+x2,data=df2,family="binomial"))
```

Question: What is the ultimate implication to have in dataset both states of target variable (0, 1) binary for the same (continuous) explanatory variables?

I have a dataset with identical variables have opposing target variable (so instead of 0 is 1).

```
> data.frame(y=c(y1[1],y2[1]),v1=c(v1[1],v1[1]),v2=c(v2[1],v2[1]))
```

y         v1       v2
1 1 -0.6264538 1.134965
2 0 -0.6264538 1.134965
In my earlier question @Dave answered that this is ok, to have same variables observed for both states 0, 1 (target variable) as this represents just uncertainty and the this is reflected in the model being uncertain with 0.5 probability.

Here below I run simulation which shows that with 1/2 cases for the same explanatory variables with both states of 1 and 0 (target variable). Here the probability predict() does not output this (doesn't converge to 50% with 1/2 such cases).

But on another point. The problem I'm having is that, when I order the model explanatory variables along with model probabilities output, I do not any longer observe monotonicity in the probability, here the variable is ordered from min to max, where min is the worst outcome (should have probability close to 1) and max variable should have model output prob. close to 0. Because of the mix 0/1 of response for identical variables affects this. I see this as a data error issue that should be investigated and cases where 0 and 1 is observed for identical variables some of those (either 0 or 1) should be dropped as this leads to actual bias (break in monotonicity = where we expect give observable explanatory variable, we expect to have the correct prob>0.5 or prob<0.5 (at least on balance) correct rank ordering).

```
     set.seed(1)
v1 = rnorm(1000)           # some continuous variables 
v2 = rnorm(1000)
z = 1 + 2*v1 + 3*v2        # linear combination with a bias
pr = 1/(1+exp(-z))         # pass through an inv-logit function
y1 = rbinom(1000,1,pr)      # bernoulli response variable
y2 = abs(y1-1)      # bernoulli response variable


sample.q <- seq(10,500,,50); #as.vector(quantile(1:length(y1), probs = seq(.1,.5,,100)))
list.out <- list();


for(j in 1:length(sample.q)){
    
    #now feed it to glm:
    df1 = data.frame(y=c(y1,y2[1:(sample.q[j])]),v1=c(v1,v1[1:(sample.q[j])]),v2=c(v2,v2[1:(sample.q[j])]))
    summary(glm( y~v1+v2,data=df1,family="binomial"))
    
    fit <- glm( y~v1+v2,data=df1,family="binomial")
    predict(fit, newdata = df1[c(1, (length(v2)+1)), ], type = c("response"))
    df1[c(1, (length(v2)+1)), ]
    
    length(y2[1:sample.q])/length(y2)
    # [1] 0.01
    
    fit <- glm( y~v1+v2,data=df1,family="binomial")
    list.out[[j]]<- data.frame(prob=predict(fit, newdata = df1[c(1, (length(v2)+1)), ], type = c("response")), 
                               obs=df1[c(1, (length(v2)+1)), ], 
                               proportion_01=length(y2[1:(sample.q[j])])/length(y2))
}
```

Comment: I think the edit is trying to duplicate the data but with the opposite outcome for each feature vector. However, what do you mean about the p-value being $1$ and achieving a perfect fit?

Comment: @Dave, I have added now the outcome of the regression fit, with the p-value `pr(>|z|)` == 1. I understand this that you can predict the outcome (given the observed variable) with 100% since both outcomes now refer to 0 and 1 at both times. The duplicate data is exactly now 1:1 split with each observed variable (v1, v2) produce both outcomes, 0 and 1. I think this is what you were referring to, right? thanks.

Comment: Reading the edit, that looks like a model with a very poor fit that cannot distinguish between classes at all. Given the synthetic data, this is correct performance, but I am not sure why you regard it as a perfect fit. Could you please explain?

Comment: Well, the data just utilizes the 100% duplication (the example before we had only 1% of duplication, so 10 cases where the same variables have both 0 and 1 target), this 1:1 duplication has basically the same 0 and 1 duplication, meaning the same variables have 0 and 1 both in the same time.

Comment: See my EDIT2, this is what you were referring, the 0.50 but this in case when there is balance 1:1 of both states 0 and 1 (see EDIT).

Comment: Please see my EDIT 3.

Comment: What are you trying to show in your edits?

Comment: I'm trying to say that the prob outcome depends on the number of cases present in the dataset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s fine. It just means that the model is unsure about the outcome for those values of the features. Given that both outcomes have happened for those feature values, the model should be uncertain about this.

Depending on how you’ve done the modeling, this might be reflected in a predicted probability around $0.5$, indicating a model that is unsure. While we like certain estimates, obtaining them might not be realistic.

To draw an analogy to linear models, a basic ANOVA has a model with many distinct outcomes for each factor level and has no issue with this. If generalized linear models like logistic regression really are generalized linear models, they ought to be able to do this, too. (Indeed, the [G-test](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/G-test) and even the [chi-squared test](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/570579/247274) are examples of this.)

Comment: indeed Dave, thanks, see my Edit.

Comment: based on my `Edit 3` the prob. outcome of the logistic regression differs if we have 100% duplicate of the 0 and 1 (opposing outcome given model variables) or only 1% inclusion of the duplicate 0 and 1 (given same model variables). This affects the probability outcome given data (somewhat understandable) but again this 0.50 predicted probability is only true if you have 1:1 sample (equal proportion observating 0 or 1 given model variables).

Comment: Can you perhaps expand and provide `r` example with the 1% or 10% and 100% inclusion of the 0 and 1 states given same observable variables? thanks. Or otherwise, can you demonstrate by example to lead to your conclusion of 0.5 prob.?

Comment: can you please present a example with the example data I have provided (in last edit 3) how this can be ok if there are more cases with target 0 compared to target 1 for the same factors?

Comment: @Maximilian Please explain what you're doing in that piece of code and what particular output confuses you and why. // Your code does not compile, but changing `x2` to `v2` allowed the code to run. Is that what you meant?

Comment: Sorry if this is not clear. I'm trying to change the ratio of 0/1 ratio for the same variables in the dataset. If the variables are the same and we have exactly the split 0/1 50:50 we obtain the "indifference" you are referring to that gives the model prob. of 50%.  However if I change the split of target 0/1 to 90% of 0 and 10% of target y=10% for the same variables the model prob. output changes (as well as model param.). So after all it depends on the data. (target ratio of 1 and 0).

Comment: @Maximilian Thank you for the clarification. What output confuses you, and why does it confuse you?

Comment: Thank you for your patience. When I use the `predict()` (see edit 3): `predict(fit, newdata = df1[c(1, (length(x2)+1)), ], type = c("response")); ` the prob   for the is `1  1001` 
`0.94244 0.94244` having to observe the identical variables, changing the estimation dataset proportions naturally gives different probabilities (since the proportion for the identical variables, change only in target proportion of 0 and 1 changes) give different prob. So the conclusion for me is that the is matters to look at on the proportion of target (1/0) given identical variables for those.

Comment: Having said that, I don't understand your part of reply: `It’s fine. It just means that the model is unsure about the outcome for those values of the features.` To me certainly it matters to look on the proportion of 0/1 for the identical variables.

Comment: the problem I'm having with your reply is that, when I order the variable along with model prob. output, I do not any longer observe monotonicity in the probability, here the variable is ordered from min to max, where min is the worst outcome (should have probabiltiy close to 1) and max variable should have model ouput prob. close to 0. Because of the mix 0/1 of response for identical variables affects this. I see this as a data error issue that should be investigated.

Comment: @Maximilian It might make sense to ask a new question about this particular issue. Between your question edits and comments, it is difficult to respond here.

Comment: Dave, I have now posted new question: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/602543/logistic-regression-with-opposing-states-both-0-and-1-with-same-identical-vari