# Chi-square test of association reporting in APA

Tags: chi-squared-test, reporting, psychology

Hello I'm really confused as to wether I'm reporting my data correctly.
Independent variable : expert or non-expert
Dependent variable: agreement with statement (strongly disagree, disagree, neither, agree strongly agree)
chi-square test run for each statement (14 in total)

this is an example for how how I have written it up in my results section:

Chi-square was run to examine the relationship between expertise and views on 'does not matter at what point during an investigation'. The relationship was significant X2 (14.6, N=37)=0.629, p = 0.006. Experts were more likely than laypeople to disagree with the statement.

Comment: Why would you choose to use chi-squared (which ignores ordering) with an ordered categorical variable? Surely the *interesting* hypothesis to pursue relates to whether experts might agree more (or perhaps less; no doubt there's also an anticipated direction but perhaps you want to pursue a two tailed alternative) with the statement, which necessitates *not*  throwing the information in that ordering out? I note that the conclusion in your last sentence would be consistent with the point I am making.

Comment: Adding to @Glen_b 's point, chi-square is not usually used when you have a dependent variable and an independent variable. You should consider logistic reg.

Comment: @PeterFlom [Note the relationship between the chi-squared test and a score test of nested logistic regression models.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/570544/247274)

Comment: Could you clarify what the 14.6 and 0.629 represent here? It's a little unclear

Comment: @Dave OK, cool. But logistic regression gives you other output that will be useful.